# What is the difference between 00.9 and 000.9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am trying to build a chatbot on Amazon Lex platform. I am using a built in slot i.e Number and validating it for less than 1(). when I am providing the slot value `00.9`, it is working fine but when I am sending `000.9` value in number slot, it is treating it as `9`.

I wanted to know why is it so?

```
def validate_yoe(slots):
    yoe1 = safe_float(try_ex(lambda: slots['YOE']))
    if yoe1 is not None and yoe1 < 1.00:
        return build_validation_result(False,
                                       'YOE',
                                       'Sorry, but you should have atleast 1 year of experience. We will wait for you untill you get that much experience. Better Luck Next Time'
        )

    return build_validation_result(True, None, None)
```

Comment: You probably want to start by printing the value of `slots['YOE']` and then `yoe1` after it is defined and see what that reveals... but another question occurs: why would you expect a number to be either 00.9 or 000.9?  Neither of those seem like sensible/meaningful/valid numbers.

Comment: Chatbot has to be deployed on an organisation website. So, it has to be universally correct as users who will use it can input anything. That is why, it needs to be validated.